# Shift pandas columns based on number of Empty columns

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am parsing several tables from the internet using pandas.read_html. Information comes from pages like this one http://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/players/william-fuller-2/gamelog/.  This provides me with dataframes like the following, which I have abbreviated to save space:

```
Passing    Rushing    tackles      Rk     Year
1          2          Nan           Nan     Nan
2          3          Nan           Nan     Nan
3          3          Nan           Nan     Nan
4          5          Nan           Nan     Nan
```

The reason that this occurs is that there are major and minor headers for each table and read_html takes both as a column name, so there are the same number of extra columns as grouped headers. I want to shift all the column names left by the number of totally Nan columns, so that my df becomes

```
Rk       Year
1          2  
2          3          
3          3              
4          5
```

To be clear, the number of totally NaN columns changes for each table, so I cannot just hardcode in a shift of a certain length.

Is there an easy way that I can do this??

It may also work if I were to find a way of reading in the table while skipping the over_header 'tr' tag.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may many ways to to this, but I achieved column counting robustness like below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your_data.csv')

to_shift = len(df.dropna(how='all', axis=1).columns)

df2 = df.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
df2.columns = df.columns[-to_shift:]

print df2

   Rk  Year
0   1     2
1   2     3
2   3     3
3   4     5
```

Comment: Great thank you! I figured it would include dropna in some fashion but was struggling with the column indexing thereafter!